# Unable to get some tabular content available in page source from a webpage using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the tabular content from a [webpage](https://www.health.gov.il/Subjects/KidsAndMatures/child_development/Pages/ADHD_experts.aspx). The problem is when I use hardcoded cookies from the browser within the headers in the script, I can see the tabular content in the console, otherwise when I get rid of cookies, I get 200 response without the required content. By the time I pasted the code here, the cookies might have already been expired.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.health.gov.il/Subjects/KidsAndMatures/child_development/Pages/ADHD_experts.aspx'

headers = {
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36",
    "Cookie":'ASP.NET_SessionId=hsqyvzg5jgkzfvzadzsyxdwx; p_hosting=!+bizF/4qwD7oEFze0NvCZLoPxuY/qnj9vRDa16ox8qkWDZTqjX1X9ZUoroByq7ynIZpFpUltU2jMCtk=; _ga=GA1.3.2020672306.1604911293; _gid=GA1.3.1145592749.1604911293; _hjTLDTest=1; _hjid=b62d7912-acfd-4ded-8a37-ae8b333fec04; WSS_FullScreenMode=false; _hjIncludedInPageviewSample=1; BotMitigationCookie_14016509088757896949="210109001604917723jho9/3TYoZILQoHOaZvAPwJt1Q8="; _gat_UA-72144815-4=1'
}

r = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
print(soup.select_one('table:has(> caption.resultsSummaryPhones)'))
```

> How can I get the tabular content using requests without using hardcoded cookies?

Comment: Can you please add an alternative url of the above URL where the content of website is in english

Comment: Sorry @Vin, that is the only link I've. I'm trying to get the response having the required content. The rest I can handle myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the hard-coded cookies, you might want to consider using `selenium` with a `webdriver` in `headless` mode.

For example:

```
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://www.health.gov.il/Subjects/KidsAndMatures/child_development/Pages/ADHD_experts.aspx')
time.sleep(1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser").select_one('table:has(> caption.resultsSummaryPhones)')

phone_numbers = [
    n.getText(strip=True) for n
    in soup.find_all("td", {"class": "phoneBookListWorkPhone"})
    if n.getText(strip=True)
]

print(phone_numbers)
```

Output:

```
['02-5630147', '08-9330328', '03-6287200', '08-9703940', '08-8505515', '02-6413026', '04-6727000', '03-6302211', '04-8377717', '02-9939555       02-5887300', '04-9551155', '074-7034622']
```